# Windows Phone Brightness Nokia Lumina 520

Tags: 8.0

While testing an application I am building, the phone screen starts to dim even while I am interacting with the application.  It than brightens again and I did not do any extra functionality .  It does this back and forth.  I have the phone fully charged due to it being plugged in via USB but was curious if anyone had run into the phone acting in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your brightness set to auto? Perhaps it is having trouble detecting the amount of light indoors when you are interacting with it (you might be moving over the sensor). Try changing it to a manual value:

1. Open settings Settings
2. Tap Brightness
3. Tap the Automatically Adjust slider to switch it Off
4. Set an appropriate value.

Comment: The brightness was set to auto and I adjusted it to the medium setting.  I have not seen the dimming effect happen after that so far.